# Converting date object to string and then in date again

Tags: php, mongodb, datetime

I am really new to mongo db. The problem I am having is that I am storing the date into db like this **Jun 23, 1912** and it is stored as **1912-06-23 00:00:00**. It works fine for adding but in case of edit, I need to repopulate the form with the date field as well but I am having this error  **Catchable fatal error: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string**. I have done the `var_dump()` and it is returning me the object. Following is the `var_dump()`

```
 object(DateTime)[454]
          public 'date' => string '1912-06-23 00:00:00' (length=19)
          public 'timezone_type' => int 1
          public 'timezone' => string '+00:00' (length=6)
```

I need a help to convert the date back into **Jun 23, 1912**. I am using Php with for this

Comment: Looking at the methods of PHP's DateTime object might help - http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php - format(), for example, is useful for displaying the date

Comment: But formatting a PHP DateTime object for display has nothing to do with Mongo DB

Comment: I have not done any thing to convert the **Jun 23, 1912** to **1912-06-23 00:00:00**

Comment: What's translating the string `Jun 23, 1912` to `1912-06-23 00:00:00`? MongoDB doesn't do that automatically. You just need to reverse the process. (Convert a `DateTime` to a string).

Comment: There is no script for this job. I am also surprised

Comment: PHP is doing this, you need to use the `format` function as shown in this recent question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16809728/383478

Comment: Why Php is doing so? I have not written any piecw of code for this

Comment: The only way I can tell you that is if you show your full code and you tell me what php version and what php mongodb driver you are using

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend converting to an integer before storing in MongoDB, its easier for searching and requires less data to be stored within the database.  Converting back and forth between the DateTime class and the integer is easy in PHP (see DateTime constructor).